# Entity ID as input model field vs action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models, crud

Should an input model for creating or updating entities have an ID field to identify the entity, or should your edit action accept an ID parameter?

## Compare

### Input Model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(EntityInputModel input)
{
    var entity = _unitOfWork.CurrenSession.Get<MyEntity>(input.Id);
    // do editing
    // ...
}
```

### Action Parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(Guid id, EntityInputModel input)
{
    var entity = _unitOfWork.CurrenSession.Get<MyEntity>(id);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer the first. I always define a specific view model for each POST action. So if this action requires an `id` I include it as part of this specific view model.